# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {this}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This gives an error:
how to solve this problem in react
its file of layout
i m using visual studio

```js
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.identify = this.identify.bind(this);
  }
  identify() {
    if (this.props.dashboard) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Container>{this.props.children}</Container>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="flexible-content">
          <TopNavigation />
          <SideNavigation />
          <main id="content" className="p-5">
            {this.props.children}
          </main>
          <DashFooter />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return { this: this.identify };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `identify` method which returns JSX in your case

```
render() {
    return this.identify();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return valid JSX from the render function. Right now you're returning an object of { this: this.identify }.
You just need to return this.identify()